# Wireshark decrypt TLS 1.2 from WCF client

Tags: tls, decryption, wireshark, wcf

I have managed to decrypt TLS 1.2 data using Wireshark on a connection from the browser to the WCF service, but cannot manage to do the same with the WCF client.

I'm not sure what is the difference, because in both cases the cipher suite seems to be Cipher Suite: `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)`.

I'm using the (Pre)-Master-Secret method by setting the SSLKEYLOGFILE env variable.

Comment: Could you post more information, like dumps of TLS handshakes and how exactly you're extracting pre master secrets?

Comment: I've set the SSLKEYLOGFILE env variable, but wouldn't feel confortable in sharing the TLS handshakes in this case.